# Redireccionar subdominios de nivel superior al subdominio de primer nivel con nginx

Tags: nginx

Cuento con un certificado SSL Wildcard y nginx. Deseo redireccionar subdominios de nivel superior al subdominio de primer nivel.

Por ejemplo: 
Si tengo http://subdominio3.subdominio2.subdominio1.dominio.tld
lo deseo redireccionar a: https://subdominio1.dominio.tld

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la siguiente configuración en nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name  ~^(?<anyelse>.*)\.(?<subdomain>[\w-]+)\.com\.pe$;

    return  301  https://$subdomain.com.pe$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    server_name ~^(?<anyelse>.*)\.(?<subdomain>[\w-]+)\.com\.pe$;

    return      https://$subdomain.com.pe$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>[\w-]+)\.com\.pe$;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;" always;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: El bloque de en medio debiera también referenciar el certificado y, en la práctica, creo que el primer y el segundo bloque podrían ser un solo bloque escuchando en ambos puertos y referenciando el certificado